How to set tooltip on regular view in android?
I am trying to follow this link and add tooltip without using any library
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/tooltips
I was trying to set tooltip in ConstraintLayout via xml and in the code like this
container.tooltipText = "Send an email"
But nothing shows up.
Can you recommend how to set it up or maybe some not very old library?

"But nothing shows up" -- how are you triggering it to display?

share your code!

Tooltip Library Recommendation
I recommend using a well-maintained library like Skydoves' Balloon for showing tooltips. It's easy to use, flexible and offers ease of customization.
You can show tooltips around any view with this library.
Example Code
Here's an example of how I'm using the Balloon library in my project:
Kotlin
fun getToolTip(
    ctx: Context?, 
    message: CharSequence, 
    @androidx.annotation.FloatRange arrowPosition: Float
): Balloon {
    return Balloon.Builder(ctx!!)
        .setArrowSize(10)
        .setAutoDismissDuration(1500)
        .setArrowOrientation(ArrowOrientation.TOP)
        .setArrowPosition(arrowPosition)
        .setTextSize(15f)
        .setPaddingRight(16)
        .setPaddingLeft(16)
        .setHeight(56)
        .setCornerRadius(8f)
        .setAlpha(0.9f)
        .setDismissWhenClicked(true)
        .setText(message)
        .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.white))
        .setTextIsHtml(true)
        .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.edGreen))
        .setBalloonAnimation(BalloonAnimation.OVERSHOOT)
        .build()
}

Link of Github: https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon
